# PRE_SETA_DATA CLOSED

Tags: php, forms, symfony, events

Hi i got my OrderType form.

Here is my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
              ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
              'data' => $options['client'],
              'mapped' => false,
              'attr' => ['class' => 'chosen-select','data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz klienta'],
              'class' => UserDetails::class,
              'choice_label' => function ($client) {
              return  ''.$firma.' '.$client->getJson()["client"]["imie"] .' '. $client->getJson()["client"]["nazwisko"].'';
               },
              'label' => 'Wybierz klienta'))


               ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
               'label' => 'Zapisz',
               'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']]) ;

    $builder->addEventListener( 
              FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) {
                       $form = $event->getForm();
                       $client =$form->get('client')->getData();
                       $shipping = null === $client ? array() : $client->getClientsShippings()->getJson()["clients_shippings"]["name"];

           $form->add('shipping', EntityType::class, array(
               'class' => ClientsShippings::class,
               'placeholder' => '',
               'choices' => $shipping));
             }
           );
}
```

There are no errors, but nothing happens either. I do not know how to achieve that, after selecting the EventListener client, PRE_SET_DATA loaded the shipping addresses assigned to the client in the ClientsShippings entity depending on the chosen client.
I read this one a few times on symfony.com, but I can not completely understand these events.

Could someone help me run it, let me have an example of how it works. Maybe I think about it completely in a different way.

Comment: and i don`t know why but this   $client =$form->get('client')->getData();  is null,

Comment: I'd start with reformatting the code and separating this mess into neat chunks, eah assigned to corresponding variables.

Comment: I edited code, is better now.

Comment: So can someone help ?